# Gitlab ci job to validate/update version on merge create

Tags: windows, powershell, gitlab-ci-runner

Im trying to integrate a version validation/update step into our pipeline. ( windows runner, powershell )

version 1 would be to ensure the version file has changed. tried available [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224153/how-to-make-sure-a-file-was-changed-with-gitlab-ci) but the variable $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA is not resolved/expanded

```yml
check-version:
  stage: validate
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "pre-release")
  script:
    - 'git fetch'
    - '$FILES_CHANGED = @(git diff --name-only $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA...HEAD)'
    - './validate-version.ps1 $FILES_CHANGED'
```

( tried following writings: ${VAR}, $VAR, "$VAR", "${VAR}" )

version 2 would update the version directly and add it to the merge commit. based on commit message it pass different parameter to update script

```yml
version-update:
  stage: merge
  variables:
    UPDATE: 'patch'
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "pre-release") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /[mM][aA][jJ][oO][rR]/) 
      variables: 
        UPDATE: 'major'
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "pre-release") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /[mM][iI][nN][oO][rR]/)
      variables: 
        UPDATE: 'minor'
    - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "pre-release")
  script: 
    - './update-version.ps1 $UPDATE' # update version in file
    - 'git config user.email "***'
    - 'git config user.name "Gitlab CI"'
    - 'git remote set-url --push git@gitlab:$CI_PROJECT_PATH'
    - 'git add ****'
    - 'git commit -m "Version update"'
    - 'git push HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME'
```

This job is completly ignored with no log entry ( even with the same rule just like check-version ).
log:

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in ****
Checking out 91c37042 as detached HEAD (ref is refs/merge-requests/4/head)...
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Job succeeded
```

Additionaly, the jobs should only be created when a merge-request is created. currently both version are run on every push to the source branch.

would appreciate any hints on errors/problems with these job configurations.
( note: both stages are defined under the global stages )